# how to insert multiple record at a time in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

i want to insert multiple records at time with in a loop using hibernate

i have tried with below code

service method which calls insert method

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean addTermdates(FeeTermDates feetermdates) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return theMasterDao.addTermdates(feetermdates);
    }
```

DAO

```
@Override
    public boolean addTermdates(FeeTermDates feetermdates) {

        int termid=feetermdates.getFeeTerms().getTermId();
        FeeTerms feeTerms=new FeeTerms();
        feeTerms.setTermId(termid);
         boolean success = false;
         try {
                currentSession=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

                String stringDate=feetermdates.getDate();
                FeeTermDates feeDate=null;
                String val[]=stringDate.split(",");
                int i=0;
                for(String date:val)
                {
                    i++;

                    feeDate=new FeeTermDates();
                    feeDate.setFeeTerms(feeTerms); 
                    feeDate.setDate(date);
                    currentSession.save(feeDate);    

                }  


                success=true;  

         }  
         catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return success;
    }
```

but it inserts only **one record after the Exception is thrown** .please have look on  Exception

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.rasvek.cg.entity.FeeTermDates#0]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:683)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at com.rasvek.cms.dao.MasterDaoImpl.addTermdates(MasterDaoImpl.java:380)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1553.addTermdates(Unknown Source)
    at com.rasvek.cms.service.MasterSeviceImpl.addTermdates(MasterSeviceImpl.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1554.addTermdates(Unknown Source)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.MasterController.addTermdates(MasterController.java:600)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.MasterController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2eff8c2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.MasterController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8a38b6e5.addTermdates(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Hibernate: insert into campus_guru_01.fee_term_dates (date, term_id, tdm_id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

**> is it possible to do so in hibernate ?**

if yes .please help me out.

**edit**

```
package com.rasvek.cg.entity;
// Generated May 14, 2018 11:39:07 PM by Hibernate Tools 5.1.7.Final

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

/**
 * FeeTerms generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "fee_terms", catalog = "campus_guru_01")
public class FeeTerms implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer termId;
    private String termName;
    private String termCount;
    private Set<FeeTermDates> feeTermDateses = new HashSet<FeeTermDates>(0);
    private Set<AssocFeeTerms> assocFeeTermses = new HashSet<AssocFeeTerms>(0);

    public FeeTerms() {
    }

    public FeeTerms(String termName, String termCount, Set<FeeTermDates> feeTermDateses,
            Set<AssocFeeTerms> assocFeeTermses) {
        this.termName = termName;
        this.termCount = termCount;
        this.feeTermDateses = feeTermDateses;
        this.assocFeeTermses = assocFeeTermses;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "term_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getTermId() {
        return this.termId;
    }

    public void setTermId(Integer termId) {
        this.termId = termId;
    }

    @Column(name = "term_name")
    public String getTermName() {
        return this.termName;
    }

    public void setTermName(String termName) {
        this.termName = termName;
    }

    @Column(name = "term_count", length = 45)
    public String getTermCount() {
        return this.termCount;
    }

    public void setTermCount(String termCount) {
        this.termCount = termCount;
    }  

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "feeTerms")
    public Set<FeeTermDates> getFeeTermDateses() {
        return this.feeTermDateses;
    }  

    public void setFeeTermDateses(Set<FeeTermDates> feeTermDateses) {
        this.feeTermDateses = feeTermDateses;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "feeTerms")
    public Set<AssocFeeTerms> getAssocFeeTermses() {
        return this.assocFeeTermses;
    }

    public void setAssocFeeTermses(Set<AssocFeeTerms> assocFeeTermses) {
        this.assocFeeTermses = assocFeeTermses;
    }

}
```

FeeTermDates.java

```
package com.rasvek.cg.entity;
// Generated May 14, 2018 11:39:07 PM by Hibernate Tools 5.1.7.Final

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

/**
 * FeeTermDates generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "fee_term_dates", catalog = "campus_guru_01")
public class FeeTermDates implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int tdmId;
    private FeeTerms feeTerms;
    private String date;

    public FeeTermDates() {
    }

    public FeeTermDates(int tdmId, FeeTerms feeTerms) {
        this.tdmId = tdmId;
        this.feeTerms = feeTerms;
    }

    public FeeTermDates(int tdmId, FeeTerms feeTerms, String date) {
        this.tdmId = tdmId;
        this.feeTerms = feeTerms;
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Id

    @Column(name = "tdm_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getTdmId() {
        return this.tdmId;
    }

    public void setTdmId(int tdmId) {
        this.tdmId = tdmId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "term_id", nullable = false)
    public FeeTerms getFeeTerms() {
        return this.feeTerms;  
    }  

    public void setFeeTerms(FeeTerms feeTerms) {
        this.feeTerms = feeTerms;
    }

    @Column(name = "date")
    public String getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

But your problem based on the stacktrace seems to indicate that when you insert the second `FeeTermDates` entity, it is being assigned the same primary key `0`.

If you are mapping your entity primary key to be manually assigned, as shown below, that you are properly assigning the value in your loop.

```
@Id
private Integer id;
```

Another option is to let the database assign it for you by letting the database generate the value for you so you can focus on just constructing the entity with business data:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
```

My guess is you're using option (1) but you aren't assigning the value.  My suggestion would be to use option (2) for your use case if possible.

Comment: thank you @Naros .i will add entity classes please look on them.